# Dagger2: How no to duplicate Module-Component forActivity / Fragments, relying on single Base(Module/Component) for Base(Activity/Fragment) &

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

Given BaseFragment and its subclasses: DerivedFragmentA, DerivedFragmentB, ...

Let's say, that most of `@Inject` fields are common for each fragment and hence declared in BaseFragment:

```
abstract class BaseFragment : DaggerFragment() {
    @Inject lateinit var vmFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory
}

class DerivedFragmentA : BaseFragment()
class DerivedFragmentB : BaseFragment()
...
```

For each of derived fragments we have to **manually** create Module-Component pairs, such as:

```
@Subcomponent
interface DerivedFragmentAComponent : AndroidInjector<DerivedFragmentA> {

    @Subcomponent.Builder
    abstract class Builder : AndroidInjector.Builder<DerivedFragmentA>()
}

@Module(subcomponents = [DerivedFragmentAComponent::class])
abstract class DerivedFragmentAModule {

    @Binds @IntoMap @FragmentKey(DerivedFragmentA::class)
    abstract fun bind(builder: DerivedFragmentAComponent.Builder): AndroidInjector.Factory<out Fragment>
}
```

And install each of them to some outer component, like that:

```
@Subcomponent(modules = [DerivedFragmentAModule::class, DerivedFragmentBModule::class, ...])
interface MainComponent : AndroidInjector<MainActivity> {

    @Subcomponent.Builder
    abstract class Builder : AndroidInjector.Builder<MainActivity>()
}
```

But this is kind of boilerplate.

If we try to make just a single Module-Component for BaseFragment and install only it to the MainComponent - we will get a runtime exception during invocation of `AndroidInjector.inject(fragment)` method, with the following message:

```
  "No injector factory bound for Class<DerivedFragmentA>. Injector factories were bound for supertypes of DerivedFragmentA: BaseFragment. Did you mean to bind an injector factory for the subtype?"
```

Is there any way to fix that and avoid code duplication? Or as Dagger-2 strongly relies on classnames, its [impossible](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/653) ?

Comment: Indeed you need to inject concrete class, you cannot do otherwise but you don't need to ceate subcomponent manually, use `@ContributesAndroidInjector`
You may have a look to my template project https://github.com/SamYStudiO/beaver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Injection with Dagger 2 always works with the type you specify. `inject(fragment : BaseFragment)` will only ever inject the fields of `BaseFragment` and none of the fields declared in any subclasses. That's just something you have to keep in mind.

You say you would like to just declare one component and inject things into the `BaseFragment` only, so that's exactly what you *can* do. Instead of creating a subcomponent for your `DerivedFragment` you create one for your `BaseFragment`...

```
@Subcomponent
interface BaseFragmentComponent : AndroidInjector<BaseFragment> {

    @Subcomponent.Builder
    abstract class Builder : AndroidInjector.Builder<BaseFragment>()
}
```

Then you can bind the `BaseFragment.Builder` to your `DerivedFragmentX`s.

```
@Module(subcomponents = [BaseFragmentComponent::class])
abstract class BaseFragmentModule {

    @Binds @IntoMap @FragmentKey(DerivedFragmentA::class)
    abstract fun bind(builder: BaseFragmentComponent.Builder): AndroidInjector.Factory<out Fragment>

    @Binds @IntoMap @FragmentKey(DerivedFragmentB::class)
    abstract fun bind(builder: BaseFragmentComponent.Builder): AndroidInjector.Factory<out Fragment>

    @Binds @IntoMap @FragmentKey(DerivedFragmentC::class)
    abstract fun bind(builder: BaseFragmentComponent.Builder): AndroidInjector.Factory<out Fragment>
}
```

The important bit is to set `@FragmentKey(DerivedFragmentA::class)` to reference the subclass, since that's the one Dagger will look up when calling `AndroidInjection.inject(fragment)`.

---

I'd still recommend you not to use this approach, as you'd end up with a mix of some fragments being fully injected and others where it's just the BaseFragment. This sounds confusing to me.

You could just use [`@ContributesAndroidInjector`](https://google.github.io/dagger/android) instead to generate the boilerplate code for you and properly inject every fragment.